# Was annihilation considered in 1905?

Tags: energy

The positron was discovered in 1932, did physicist have any knowledge or  assumed that matter could be annihilated into energy at the start of XX century?

Comment: Does  "E = mc^2" count?  which is to say,  matter/energy conversion has a lot more avenues than antiparticles.

Comment: Annihilation is a more specific concept than matter-to-energy conversion. The former requires antimatter, first theorised c. 1930 from the Dirac equation. But the fact that all exothermic reactions are due to converting mass to energy followed from special relativity in 1905. For example, chemicals undergo small changes in reactions. How *much* of a change are you looking for? Does chemistry count? Do nuclear reactions?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft,...such as?

Comment: @J.G., The question  means: before 1905 and relativity. What was knownbefore that date?

Comment: Heat from a 'non chemical' source was known. See https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/7475/when-was-it-first-noticed-or-demonstrated-that-radioactive-material-became-war/7482#7482

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Let us consider the following info on developments prior to 1905.**

- Before 1905 (The forthcoming of $E = mc^2$)
  **1881** J. J. Thompson proposed that a charged conductor in motion increases its mass by $\frac{4}{15} e^2/a$
- **1904** H. A. Lorentz proposed that $m_L = m_0 (1 – v^2/c^2)^{-3/2}$ based on deformable spherical charge.
- **1904** Hasenöhrl derived an apparent mass increase of a moving cavity containing electromagnetic energy E, obtaining  $m_e = \frac{8}{3} E/c^2$.
- 1905 On Abraham’s suggestion, Hasenöhrl corrected this to  $m_e = \frac{4}{3} E/c^2$

Based on the study of the historical development of concepts, one may deduce that the equation $E = mc^2$ would have been discovered by other physicists sooner or later. However, it is likely that Einstein merely accelerated the development.
ref.- >https://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/EJ848449.pdf

our contention is that though annihilation of particles was not an acceptable concept prior to 1905 but other ways of energy conversion of mass was being attempted.

Comment: @uhoh-many thanks for the editing..with MathJax it looks good...somehow I am not conversant with it..though its simple...

Comment: @uhoh-thanks sir..i am 76 yr old and barely write with one finger..i will try..

Comment: well you certainly write some thoughtful and authoritative answers with that finger! I don't know if you like to drift to other SE sites, but I have a math history question that hasn't received enough attention so far: [How has the definition of the complex logarithm evolved since Cotes (1682-1716)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2395338/284619)

Comment: thanks ...basically, I am a nuclear physics person but have used maths as a tool-i will try to look up...my experience in using complex logarithm is very limited

Comment: here's a tough one then: [Has a nuclear “neutron halo” been measured directly? Anything other than “breaks easily”?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/365389/83380)

Comment: @uhoh-just came across a study on neutron halo  interaction-pl.see<https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370269316304890>

Comment: Oh, it's fairly recent and open access as well, thanks! Still though, it's about how easily the nucleus breaks ((total) interaction cross sections). I'd still like to see if there are any other observables besides this but that should be done in Physics SE not here. Thanks for your help!